# error when try to reshape array

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

i am using 2 separate data set one for training and other for testing

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as pt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

data = pd.read_csv("train.csv").as_matrix()
data2 = pd.read_csv("test.csv").as_matrix()
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
# Dataset for training

train_data = data[0:41999,1:]
train_label = data[0:41999,0]

clf.fit(train_data,train_label)

# Dataset for Testing

test_data = data2[0:27999,1:]
actual_lable = data2[0:27999,0]
index = 5

sample = test_data[5]

sample.shape=(28,28)
pt.imshow(255-sample,cmap='gray')

print(clf.predict([test_data[5]]))
pt.show()
```

i am getting below error in line 35:

```
sample.shape=(28,28)
```

i am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 783 into shape (28,28)
```

but if i use values from the train_data then there are no errors
i.e 
instead of using

```
sample = test_data[5]
```

if i use

```
sample = train_data[5]
```

i dont get any error. Could you please explain why the above code gives error?

- List item

Comment: data[0:41999,1:] -> data[0:41999,:]

Answer (score 0):

28*28 = 784 and for your test data after your split, there are only 783 values, that's why it's causing error in your reshape process.

You will have to open your test file and see exactly how many columns are there. If there are only 784 columns, then you should do:

```
test_data = data2[0:27999,:]
```

and the true_label might be stored somewhere else.

Comment: the training data files contains the 785 columns while the testing data contains only 784 columns.. i defined both the list with 785 columns.. thanks :)